# List contains Object => Object

Tags: scala

Hi currently I try to look if a List contains an element. Currently the List holds a Object which holds another Object that should be checked.

These are the classes that the two List contains:

```
case class SourceFile(name: String, path: String, date_changed: java.util.Date)
case class DBSourceFile(id: UUID, file: SourceFile)
```

So I have two lists list1: `List[SourceFile]` and list2: `List[DBSourceFile]` 
currently i make a foreach loop to acces the SourceFile in list1:

```
for(file <- files)
```

currently i check it with count but i think a contains would be way better but i can't do something like this:

```
dbFiles.count(dbFile => dbFile.file.name == diskFile.name && dbFile.file.path == diskFile.path)
```

when i use contains

what is the prefered method ?

That's how i did it at the moment:

```
def checkExistingFilesInDB() {
  for(diskFile <- diskFiles) {
    val dbFile = dbFiles.filter(dbFile => dbFile.file.name == diskFile.name && dbFile.file.path == diskFile.path)
    if(dbFile.length == 1) {
      //println(dbFile(0))
      if(!(diskFile == dbFile(0).file)) {
        Logger.info("File updated: " + dbFile(0) + " \nwith: " + diskFile)
        SourceFile.update(DBSourceFile(dbFile(0).id, diskFile))  
      }
    }
    else if (dbFile.length == 0) { 
      SourceFile.createSourceFile(diskFile)
      Logger.info("File inserted into Database: " + diskFile)
    }
    else {
      // TODO: What happens if more than 1 reference of the file is in the database
      Logger.error("File exists two times on the database")
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `exists`

Comment: what happens if a something exists two times in a list?

Comment: `exists` will return true as soon as it determines there is at least one match.

Comment: ah okai, yeah thats enough for me. ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you doing to be using this check, precisely?  Too often, **exists** and **contains** are used in quite clunky ways and you can eliminate them entirely with more idiomatic Scala

For example, your question implies you are doing something a little like this:

```
val fileCheck = { dbFile: SourceFile => dbFile.name == diskFile.name && dbFile.path == diskFile.path }
if (list1 exists fileCheck ) {
  var Files = list1 filter fileCheck
  for (file <- Files) {
    // Do something with file
  }
}
```

You can achieve this much more cleanly with a **for** comprehension which uses a guard to filter files matching your condition, as in

```
for (file <- list1 if file.name == diskFile.name && file.path == diskFile.path) {
  // Do Something with file
}
```

On the other hand, if you wanted to do something different if there is no such match, like this:

```
val fileCheck = { dbFile: SourceFile => dbFile.name == diskFile.name && dbFile.path == diskFile.path }
if (list1 exists fileCheck ) {
  val Files = list1 filter fileCheck
  for (file <- Files) {
    // Do something with file
  }
} else {
  // Meh! No matching files.
}
```

Then you could, for example, use the **for** comprehension with **yield** to give up the list of matching files

```
val files = for (file <- list1 if file.name == diskFile.name && file.path == diskFile.path) yield file
```

And do one thing if it is empty (**Nil**) and another if it is not.  I still prefer that to using **exists** to perform the check and then reusing the check parameters to filter the list.  There are many expressive ways to do this but it depends on the context.

Note: the **for** comprehension is more functional, less imperative (particularly when used with **yield**)

**EDIT:**

OK, the above was written before you posted your code.  Firstly, in this case, I'd say you should probably stick with `val dbFile = dbFiles.filter(...`; a list comprehension doesn't get you anything extra here, so using **filter** is more clear.

Secondly, you should use **match**.  Match is almost always better than any chain of **if...else if...else**.  A simple **if...else** is fine but **else if** is error prone.

Now, you could do it like this

```
val dbFile = dbFiles.filter(dbFile => dbFile.file.name == diskFile.name && dbFile.file.path == diskFile.path
dbFiles.length match {
  case 0 => //Insert file into db
  case 1 => //Update existing db record
  case _ => //Must be more than one!  Aroogah!  Aroogah!
}
```

Which is nice and simple and will match every case.  But Christian, consider this: if you have multiple db records, all with the same name and path and there's a real file that corresponds, surely all you need to do is keep one of those records and update it, while deleting the others?  Let me show you how do do this with **match**

```
dbFile match {
  case Nil => // Empty list, insert file into db
  case first :: others => { // At least one match
    for (errorFile <- others) {
      SourceFile.delete(errorFile.id) // Assuming you have this or similar method
    }
    SourceFile.update(DBSourceFile(first.id, diskFile))
  }
}
```

This works because `first :: others` will match both a list of one or more.  If there is only one element, **others** will be **Nil**, so the for comprehension will do nothing .  Otherwise, it will contain the list of additional entries.  If you care about which of the multiple entries you keep, you probably want either the first or the last entry; you can do that by adding a **sort** (presumably by **id**) to the line that builds **dbFile**

So you get to use a for comprehension in the end ;)

Comment: Currently I updated everything with filter instead exists, my code looks like your last snippet or nearly as your last snippet.
I just check if filter gives me a list with 0, 1 or more elements, if i have more it gives an exception

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt I'm not sure if you're telling me you tried this and you get an unexpected exception or if your code is designed to throw an exception if there are more than two elements.

Comment: no, i just said that i implemented it like your snippet, with just a small change that i have an if-else which looks up the list length of the filtered list. if the filter list has 1 element it does something if the list has 0 elements it does something and if the list has more than 1 element it will throw an exception.
I'm still feeling bad, if i wrote idomatic scala. i update my question with my new code.

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt Ah, I see you updated your question.  OK, when I have time later I will come back with more suggestions.

Comment: Updated the answer.  Left the orignal, general recommendations in place and added specific ideas that match your actual code.

Comment: Wow that is really, really awesome and that's what i've been looking for.
Just one thing i don't want to delete other records i just want to log them. since it should **never** happen that there are more than one entry, but due the data comes from an smb path i'm scared that the entries could getting inconsistent, but still your example matches this case as well, just a .log instead of delete ;)
i didn't thought that match is so powerful... i'm really starting to fell in love with scala.

Comment: If you have logged them, why keep them in the db?  At least, why in the same table? You could even move them out of the main table into a duplicates table if you really wanted to keep a record.  Or you could put constraints on the db table that stop duplicates being entered at all - then you would find out exactly when something had gone wrong.

Comment: hm that's true at all. But i can't make a unique constraint on the path or at the filename, i would need to make a new column with both, the filename and filepath since filenames could aren't unique (they could occur two times, just not on the same folder)