# Is there any advantage to avoiding while loops in Scala?

Tags: scala

Reading Scala docs written by the experts one can get the impression that tail recursion is better than a while loop, even when the latter is more concise and clearer. This is one example

```
object Helpers {
    implicit class IntWithTimes(val pip:Int) {
            // Recursive
        def times(f: => Unit):Unit = {
            @tailrec
            def loop(counter:Int):Unit = {
                if (counter >0) { f; loop(counter-1) }
            }
            loop(pip)
        }

            // Explicit loop
        def :@(f: => Unit) = {
            var lc = pip
            while (lc > 0) { f; lc -= 1 }
        }   
    }
}
```

(To be clear, the expert was not addressing looping at all, but in the example they chose to write a loop in this fashion as if by instinct, which is what the raised the question for me: should I develop a similar instinct..)

The only aspect of the while loop that could be better is the iteration variable should be local to the body of the loop, and the mutation of the variable should be in a fixed place, but Scala chooses not to provide that syntax.

Clarity is subjective, but the question is does the (tail) recursive style offer improved performance?

Answer (score 20):

I'm pretty sure that, due to the limitations of the JVM, not every potentially tail-recursive function will be optimised away by the Scala compiler as so, so the short (and sometimes wrong) answer to your question on **performance** is no.

The long answer to your more general question (having an *advantage*) is a little more contrived. Note that, by using `while`, you are in fact:

1. creating a new variable that holds a counter.
2. mutating that variable.

Off-by-one errors and the perils of mutability will ensure that, on the long run, you'll introduce bugs with a `while` pattern. In fact, your `times` function could easily be implemented as:

```
def times(f: => Unit) = (1 to pip) foreach f
```

Which not only is simpler and smaller, but also avoids any creation of transient variables and mutability. In fact, if the type of the function you are calling would be something to which the results matter, then the `while` construction would start to be even more difficult to read. Please attempt to implement the following using nothing but `whiles`:

```
def replicate(l: List[Int])(times: Int) = l.flatMap(x => List.fill(times)(x))
```

Then proceed to define a tail-recursive function that does the same.

---

**UPDATE:**

I hear you saying: "hey! that's cheating! `foreach` is neither a `while` nor a `tail-rec` call". Oh really? Take a look into Scala's definition of `foreach` for `Lists`:

```
  def foreach[B](f: A => B) {
    var these = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      f(these.head)
      these = these.tail
    }
  }
```

If you want to learn more about recursion in Scala, take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/04/tail-calls-tailrec-and-trampolines.html). Once you are into functional programming, go crazy and read Rúnar's [blog post](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/tail-call-elimination-in-scala-monads/). Even more info [here](http://dynamicsofprogramming.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/loop-performance-and-local-variables-in.html) and [here](http://ochafik.com/blog/?p=806).

Comment: Scala optimizes *direct tail recursion*. However, it's not always easy to see whether a recursive call *really* is directly to the same method. In particular, even *if* a method seemingly calls itself, it might actually call an overridden or overloaded version of itself, thus making the recursion no longer direct. When in doubt, `@tailrec`.

Comment: Gotta admit I'm somewhat new to functional programming, but if decrementing a counter is a "peril" there's an awful lot of bad code out there and I think I'll go hide in my room.  :-)

Comment: Although for comprehensions with ranges look pretty much like a less general java "for" loop, they have an issue that during debugging (at least with the Intellij IDEA plugin) that single stepping does not enter the body of the "for" (you have to put a break point there), and references to variables in the outer class are not "clean". Of course these constructs are only an illusion of a loop over an incrementing index, and I wonder why Scala just does not provide syntax for this commonly used construct, even if it's use may be more limited that in other languages?

Comment: @MikeHanafey Scala lets you write `for (x <- 1 to 10) { do stuff with x }`.  How much simpler can you get?  There's just no need for special syntax for it.

Answer (score 6):

In general, a directly tail recursive function (i.e., one that always calls itself directly and cannot be overridden) will always be optimized into a `while` loop by the compiler. You can use the `@tailrec` annotation to verify that the compiler is able to do this for a particular function.

As a general rule, any tail recursive function can be rewritten (usually automatically by the compiler) as a `while` loop *and vice versa*.

The purpose of writing functions in a (tail) recursive style is not to maximize performance or even conciseness, but to make the intent of the code as clear as possible, while simultaneously minimizing the chance of introducing bugs (by eliminating mutable variables, which generally make it harder to keep track of what the "inputs" and "outputs" of the function are). A properly written recursive function consists of a series of checks for terminating conditions (using either cascading `if`-`else` or a pattern match) with the recursive call(s) (plural only if not tail recursive) made if none of the terminating conditions are met.

The benefit of using recursion is most dramatic when there are several different possible terminating conditions. A series of `if` conditionals or patterns is generally much easier to comprehend than a single `while` condition with a whole bunch of (potentially complex and inter-related) boolean expressions `&&`'d together, especially if the return value needs to be different depending on which terminating condition is met.

Comment: Thank you for the most clear answer of why actually to focus on the tail recursive functions.

Answer (score 4):

Did these experts say that performance was the reason?  I'm betting their reasons are more to do with expressive code and functional programming.  Could you cite examples of their arguments?

One interesting reason why recursive solutions *can* be more efficient than more imperative alternatives is that they very often operate on lists and in a way that uses only head and tail operations.  These operations are actually faster than random-access operations on more complex collections.

Anther reason that while-based solutions may be less efficient is that they can become very ugly as the complexity of the problem increases...

(I have to say, at this point, that your example is not a good one, since neither of your loops do anything useful.  Your recursive loop is particularly atypical since it returns nothing, which implies that you are missing a major point about recursive functions.  The **functional** bit.  A recursive function is *much* more than another way of repeating the same operation *n* times.)

While loops do not return a value and require side effects to achieve anything.  It is a control structure which only works at all for very simple tasks.  This is because each iteration of the loop has to examine *all* of the state to decide what to next.  The loops boolean expression may also have to be come very complex if there are multiple potential exit paths (or that complexity has to be distributed throughout the code in the loop, which can be ugly and obfuscatory).

Recursive functions offer the possibility of a much cleaner implementation.  A good recursive solution breaks a complex problem down in to simpler parts, then delegates each part on to another function which can deal with it - the trick being that that other function is itself (or possibly a mutually recursive function, though that is rarely seen in Scala - unlike the various Lisp dialects, where it is common - because of the poor tail recursion support).  The recursively called function receives in its parameters only the simpler subset of data and only the *relevant* state; it returns only the solution to the simpler problem.  So, in contrast to the while loop,

- Each iteration of the function only has to deal with a simple subset of the problem
- Each iteration only cares about its inputs, not the overall state
- Sucess in each subtask is clearly defined by the return value of the call that handled it.
- State from different subtasks cannot become entangled (since it is hidden within each recursive function call).
- Multiple exit points, if they exist, are much easier to represent clearly.

Given these advantages, recursion can make it easier to achieve an efficient solution.  Especially if you count maintainability as an important factor in long-term efficiency.

I'm going to go find some good examples of code to add.  Meanwhile, at this point I always recommend [The Little Schemer](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/).  I would go on about why but this is the second Scala recursion question on this site in two days, so look at my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645936/is-recursion-in-scala-very-necessary/18658489#18658489) instead.